# Given $z=x^2+2y^2$, finding $(\partial z/\partial x)_{\theta}$, where $\theta$ is the polar angle

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Given $z=x^{2}+2y^{2}$, $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, find $\left({\partial z}/{\partial x}\right)_{\theta}$.

Here's what I think, since both $x$ and $y$ can vary in general, but while calculating partial derivative with respect to $x$, we can treat $y$ to be a constant. So assuming that, $\partial z/\partial x=2x$. Now further since $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, it is itself variable, along with $\theta$.

$$\begin{aligned}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_{\theta}&=2\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} \\ &= 2\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta}\cos\theta-r\sin\theta\right)\end{aligned}$$

I am stuck here. If I rewrite $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, it gets a bit circular. Not sure how to proceed. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain the expression $(\partial z/\partial x)_\theta$   any further?

Comment: @RichardChen From what I could understand, I think it means first differentiating wrt $x$ and then wrt $\theta$.

Comment: @ParasKhosla The way I understand it is that you take the partial derivative with respect to $x$, and then you evaluate the answer at a given $\theta$

Answer (score 1):

No, this notation signifies that you must think of $z$ as a function of the variables $x$ and $\theta$ and then compute the partial derivative with respect to $x$, *fixing* $\theta$. This is standard notation in thermodynamics and other applied sciences.

Note that $y=x\tan\theta$ (except for the $y$-axis), and so
$$z=F(x,\theta) = x^2+2(x\tan\theta)^2 = x^2(1+2\tan^2\theta).$$
It follows that
$$\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_\theta=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = 2x(1+2\tan^2\theta).$$

You can get this "directly" from the chain rule by considering the mapping
$$g(x,\theta) = (x,x\tan\theta) = (x,y).$$
Then, letting $f(x,y)=x^2+2y^2$ and $F(x,\theta) = f(g(x,\theta))$, we have
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y(x,\theta)}{\partial x} =
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\tan\theta) = 2x + 4y\tan\theta = 2x+4(x\tan\theta)\tan\theta.$$